# Delphi SOAP WebService Catch Exception for logging

Tags: delphi, soap, webserver, indy

I have a Indy Server (`TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge`) which serve a WebModule (`TWebModule`), the WebModule contains these 3 components:

```
  HTTPSoapDispatcher1: THTTPSoapDispatcher;
  HTTPSoapPascalInvoker1: THTTPSoapPascalInvoker;
  WSDLHTMLPublish1: TWSDLHTMLPublish;
```

It's really a classical Delphi SOAP Server Application as generated by the template, and I added a generated SOAP Proxy from WSDL, and it works fine.

I like to log the error handled by the web server code. For example if the SOAP message is not correctly formatted. I tried to branch the following Events:

```
HTTPSoapPascalInvoker1.OnExceptionEvent
TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge1.OnException
TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge1.OnCommandError
```

But I can't get any of them to be triggered, even worst if I put a breakpoint inside them, it shows a cross which mean that this code may never be executed.

So, my question is how can I get a maximum of information about error generated by the webserver outside of my code ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There's a `try .. except` block in method `THTTPSoapDispatcher.DispatchRequest` in `Soap.WebBrokerSOAP.pas` that catches those kind of errors and genereates appropriate `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`  with `<SOAP-ENV:Fault>` in its body. It also sets `Response.StatusCode := 500`. At that point no event handler is invoked which prevents you from intercepting the exception. You can still, however, inspect the generated request in `WebModule`'s `AfterDispatch` event.

Comment: It’s doable, however I would have to parse the content of SOAPResponse: TStream to catch the error

Comment: Or else just add your own try..except around your own code

Comment: @R.Hoek it's already done, but it doesn't trigger when for example, there is an error in the soap envelope formatting.